# function call trace with radare2 or break on all function call

Tags: debugging, radare2, breakpoint, tracing

I want to script with python using r2pipe. Is there a way that when debugging I can break on each call function, thus I can get the parameter?  What's more, I won't jump into system library.
Or is there a way to do function trace, just in program's address space, not in system library?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. The python script doing that is attached below with appropriate comments.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import r2pipe

r = r2pipe.open('programName', flags=['-d'])
r.cmd('aei')

modules = r.cmd('dmm') #list all modules along with start and end addresses
modules2 = [] #modules' start addresses
moduleNames = []
#since modules is just one big string, we need to extract relevant information from it
i = 0
j = 0
while i < len(modules):
    modules2.append('')
    while modules[i] != ' ':
        modules2[j] += modules[i]
        i += 1
    while modules[i] == ' ':
        i += 1
    while modules[i] != ' ':
        i += 1
    while modules[i] == ' ':
        i += 1
    moduleNames.append('')
    while modules[i] != '\n':
        moduleNames[j] += modules[i]
        i += 1
    i += 1
    j += 1

moduleNames = [x.split('/')[len(x.split('/')) - 1] for x in moduleNames]

systemModules = {} #put here all libraries you don't want breakpoints in
systemModules['ld-2.27.so'] = 1

for i in range(len(moduleNames)):
    if moduleNames[i] not in systemModules:
        r.cmd('s ' + modules2[i]) #go to start of module i
        calls = r.cmd('/am call') #find all call instructions in this module; you can use other commands of type /a for more flexibility
        calls2 = [] #all addresses in module i where we want to put breakpoints
        k = 0
        j = 0
        while k < len(calls):
            calls2.append('')
            while calls[k] != ' ':
                calls2[j] += calls[k]
                k += 1
            while calls[k] != '\n':
                k += 1
            k += 1
            j += 1
        for k in range(len(calls2)):
            r.cmd('db ' + calls2[k]) #put breakpoint at given address
#all breakpoints set; you can now continue execution and do what you want to do at each breakpoint
print(r.cmd('db')) #list all breakpoints set
```

Not very elegant script, but gets the job done. It searches for all `call` instructions in relevant modules and puts breakpoint at each one.

For more flexibility, instead of doing `/am`, you can use other search commands available in radare2 (`/a?` for more information).